# Extract text between 2 strings?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, scrape

I have a huge HTML page that contains multiple data like this

```
<td style="font-size:24px;" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="60%">
    <strong>ID:Full Name:email@email.com:Mobile:Country</strong>
</td>
```

I want to extract the data between the tags which is `ID:Full Name:email@email.com:Mobile:Country`

So what would be the regex or any custom PHP Function?

PS: The above code is being repeated multiple times in a page and I want all that data to be stored in an array.

Answer (score 0):

As of others has said, you can just use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`. Like this:

```
$html = '<td style="font-size:24px;" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" width="60%"> <strong>ID:Full Name:email@email.com:Mobile:Country</strong></td>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$text = $xpath->query('//td/strong')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $text; // ID:Full Name:email@email.com:Mobile:Country
```